# My CoreLocation based Swift app is not asking user's permission to access location

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-location, osx-elcapitan

I am building a `CoreLocation` based app which which show user their location based on 6 parameters like **Latitude, Longitude, Horizontal Accuracy, Altitude, Vertical Accuracy, Distance Traveled**.

It suppose to ask user's permission to allow access of location at first time but I have tried resetting all simulator's settings too.

[image: This is how my Main.storyboard look like]

Gray part will be filled with map later.

This is how my **View.Controller.swift** look like:

```
//  Created by 16246 on 6/7/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 16246. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    private let LocationManager = CLLocationManager()
    private var previousPoint:CLLocation?
    private var totalMovementDistance:CLLocationDistance = 0

    @IBOutlet var latitudeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var longitudeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var horizontalAccuracy: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var altitudeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var verticalAccuracyLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var distanceTraveledLabel: UILabel!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        LocationManager.delegate = self
        LocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        LocationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        print("Authorization Status Changed to \(status.rawValue)")
        switch status {
        case .Authorized, .AuthorizedWhenInUse:
            LocationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        default:
            LocationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        let errorType = error.code == CLError.Denied.rawValue ? "Access Denied": "Error \(error.code)"
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Location Manager Error", message: errorType, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler: {action in})
        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let newLocation = (locations as [CLLocation]) [locations.count-1]

        let latitudeString = String(format: "%g\u{00B0}", newLocation.coordinate.latitude)
        latitudeLabel.text = latitudeString

        let longitudeString = String(format: "%g\u{00B0}", newLocation.coordinate.longitude)
        longitudeLabel.text = longitudeString

        let horizontalAccuracyString = String(format: "%g\u{00B0}", newLocation.horizontalAccuracy)
        horizontalAccuracy.text = horizontalAccuracyString

        let altitudeString = String(format: "%g\u{00B0}", newLocation.altitude)
        altitudeLabel.text = altitudeString

        let verticalAccuracyString = String(format: "%g\u{00B0}", newLocation.verticalAccuracy)
        verticalAccuracyLabel.text = verticalAccuracyString

        if newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0 {
            return
        }

        if newLocation.horizontalAccuracy > 100 ||
            newLocation.verticalAccuracy > 50 {
                return
        }

        if previousPoint == nil {
            totalMovementDistance = 0
        } else {
            totalMovementDistance += newLocation.distanceFromLocation(previousPoint!)
        }

        previousPoint = newLocation

        let distanceString = String(format: "%gm", totalMovementDistance)
        distanceTraveledLabel.text = distanceString

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

This is my **Info.plist** file:

[image]

This is my **Simulator**:

[image]

I want **output** like this:

[image]

I have been stuck on this since past 2 days. Pint of beer for a geek who help me to get along with this.

Comment: Check your application settings and make sure location permission hasn't already been approved/denied

Comment: I never had that pop up to let allow/deny location service. I already reset simulator 100s of time and tried running but still not able to see pop up @Paulw11

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move `LocationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()` to the `viewDidAppear` method.

EDIT:

Ok, you are asking `requestAlwaysAuthorization` but in info.plist you set the `When in usage...` key entry, so change the `requestAlwaysAuthorization` to the `requestWhenInUseAuthorization`

Comment: I do not have viewDidAppear method in my View.Controller.swift though

Comment: tried this but not any difference `override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        LocationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }`

Comment: Ok, you are asking `requestAlwaysAuthorization` but in info.plist you set the `When in usage...` key entry, so change the `requestAlwaysAuthorization` to the `requestWhenInUseAuthorization`...

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. I owe you pint of beer buddy. Thanks a lot